# Deleting rows in excel that contain a single letter in multiple cells across a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I was wondering if there was a solution to this just through a formula or shortcuts or if it was something I would need to use VBA for. The spreadsheet I am working with contains 112 rows, 31 columns, and 33 rows containing a "Y" (Y=positive for the purpose of the report this is being used for). I am trying to delete rows that do not contain a single "Y" all the way across the row(columns E-AA) so only the rows and names of people containing a "Y" somewhere in the row are left in the spread sheet. I found a snippet of VBA code from someone else that produced somewhat successful results but didn't include every row with a "Y" (I counted 33 rows containing a Y, the VBA code only showed 14).

[image]

The code I was using:

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Contains_String_Text_Value()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 112
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = "N" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

The above code produced these results:

[image]

The columns of interest containing either a "Y" or "N" in their cells are columns E through AA. If I wasn't clear enough or need to go further into detail just let me know.

Comment: In your loop use COUNTIF to count the number of Ys and delete the row if equals zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the job at hand, even though I'm sure it could be further optimized:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 112
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        For i = 5 To 27 Step 2
        If Cells(iCntr, i).Value = "N" Then
            Value = Value & " Delete"
        Else
            Value = Value & " Keep"
        End If
        Next i

        If Not InStr(Value, "Keep") > 0 Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
        Value = ""
    Next iCntr
End Sub
```

Comment: @KyleC please could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: sure thing I hit the check box so if it's not appeared as answered let me know, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

To do it using formula, filtering and copy/paste:

Add this formula to each row: `=COUNTIF($E2:$AA2,"Y")`
This will count the cells containing a single Y on it's own.

Add a filter across your data and filter to exclude `0` on the formula.

Copy and paste the filtered dataset to a new worksheet.  You could then clear the original data and re-paste over it.  Useful if you're only doing this once.

**Edit:**

To do the above procedure in VBA (but doing the delete in place rather than move to a second sheet):

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim rDataRange As Range

    'Define range to look at.  NB:  This is a basic set-up.
    'Real scenario would allow user to make selection, or find the limits of the dataset with a FindLastCell function.
    Set rDataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:AA112")

    'This block will remove any autofilters that already exist, and then put a formula to the right of the dataset
    'to count the Y.
    With rDataRange
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .Offset(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(RC5:RC27,""Y"")"
    End With

    With rDataRange
        'This block filters the dataset to only show 0 in the formula.
        'The dataset is resized to include the formula.
        With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
            .AutoFilter Field:=rDataRange.Columns.Count + 1, Criteria1:="0"
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).EntireRow.Delete 'Resized again to exclude the header.
        End With

        'The formula and filter are removed.
        .Offset(1, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).ClearContents
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```